Mean vs Mode: Distribution of Dice Rolls
Suppose we roll a single 6-sided die until we get two consecutive 6's. We call the time required to see two consecutive 6's as the "Absorption Time".
If we want to find to find out the Expected Absorption Time, we can model this problem as a Discrete Time Markov Chain and use First Step Analysis to answer this question:

State 0: No six has been rolled yet.
State 1: One six has been rolled.
State 2: Two consecutive sixes have been rolled.

Denote the expected number of rolls to reach state 2 from state i as E(i). We are interested in finding E(0).
$$E(0) = 1 + \frac{1}{6}E(1) + \frac{5}{6}E(0)$$
$$E(1) = 1 + \frac{1}{6}E(2) + \frac{5}{6}E(0)$$
$$E(2) = 0$$.
Solving via substitution:
$$E(1) = 1 + \frac{5}{6}E(0)$$
$$E(0) = 1 + \frac{1}{6}(1 + \frac{5}{6}E(0)) + \frac{5}{6}E(0)$$
$$E(0) = 42$$
I wrote an R simulation to try and study the distribution of these Absorption Times:
roll_until_two_sixes <- function() {
    count <- 0
    last_roll <- 0
    
    while(TRUE) {
        roll <- sample(1:6, 1)
        count <- count + 1
        
        if(roll == 6 && last_roll == 6) {
            break
        }
        
        last_roll <- roll
    }
    
    return(count)
}

num_rolls <- numeric(10000)

for(i in 1:10000) {
    num_rolls[i] <- roll_until_two_sixes()
}

hist(num_rolls, breaks=100, main = "Distribution of Absorption Times")


We can see that the Expected Absorption Time from the simulation is very close to the theoretical result:
> mean(num_rolls)
[1] 42.4607

My Question: When looking at the Distribution of Absorption Times, we can see that the frequencies of the times themselves are constantly descending:
num_rolls_freq <- table(num_rolls)
sorted_num_rolls <- sort(num_rolls_freq, decreasing = TRUE)

Initially, I had expected the distribution of Absorption Times to have a symmetric shaped distribution. That is, I thought there would be some threshold point in the middle
corresponding to the number of rolls with the highest frequency, and everything to the left and right of this point would be decreasing. Yet according to this graph, it seems like the rolls with the highest frequency occur at the very beginning and decrease as you move away, resulting in a non-symmetric distribution. Furthermore, it appears that the mean and the mode are significantly different in this resulting distribution.
Mathematically, can someone please help me understand why the resulting distribution looks this way. Is there some mathematical derivation for the exact form of this distribution of absorption times which can help us understand why the mean is so much different than the mode for this distribution?
Thanks!

Can't you model this as a geometric distribution?

You can easily count the strings without a $66$ as any such begins either $X$ or $6X$, where $X$ denotes any value other than $6$.  That allows you to read off the exact probabilities.   As a check, you should be able to confirm the expected value from the list of probabilities.
